# How to reload ForEach loop items after sheet is dismissed

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, reload

I'm currently adding new player inside sheet view and after I dismiss sheet view main view ForEach loop should update all items, but it doesn't.

In ViewModel I'm saving player to json file and after I have saved it I instantly fetch it.

After I save new username in sheet view it prints array with new username, but ForEach loop is not updating in view.

How to reload view after closing sheet view?

My Main View:

```
struct PlayersView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlayersViewModel

  @State var course: Course
  @State var isSelected: Bool = false
  @State private var selectedItem: [Bool]
  @State var selectedPlayers = [String]()

  init(viewModel: PlayersViewModel, course: Course) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    self._selectedItem = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, count: viewModel.players.count))
    self.course = course
  }

  var body: some View {
   VStack {
    ForEach(0..<viewModel.players.count) { item in
      PlayerCell(isSelected: selectedItem[item], player: viewModel.players[item].playerName)
        .onTapGesture {
          selectedItem[item].toggle()
          if selectedPlayers.contains(viewModel.players[item].playerName) {
            self.selectedPlayers = selectedPlayers.filter({ $0 != viewModel.players[item].playerName})
          } else {
            selectedPlayers.append(viewModel.players[item].playerName)
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

And my viewModel looks like that:

```
class PlayersViewModel: ObservableObject {

 @Published var players = [Player]()

 init() {
  readJSON()
 }

func saveJSON(username: String) {
  var array = players
  array.append(Player(playerName: username))
 do {
  let fileURL = try FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appendingPathComponent("example2.json")

  try JSONEncoder().encode(array)
    .write(to: fileURL)
  readJSON()
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
}

func readJSON() {
 do {
  let fileURL = try FileManager.default
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("example2.json")

  let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
  let players = try JSONDecoder().decode([Player].self, from: data)
  self.players = players
  print(players)
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hey, PlayersView is the code of the sheet or the code of the View you want to update? In any case, add the code of the view that is missing please.

Comment: could you show the sheet view and how you call it, since it's in this sheet you make the update.

Comment: You need to move `course` and `selectedItems` from PlayersView into the view model, otherwise you are not using SwiftUI state variables correctly, and you may run into troubles. Also, you hardly get the logic right, when you partly perform logic on the view and partly in the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your console, you'll see following warning:

> ForEach<Range, Int, ModifiedContent<Text, AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture>>> count (2) != its initial count (1). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

You could replace `0..<viewModel.players.count` with `viewModel.players.indices` to fix it

But if you do, you'll face a crash, because you're initializing `selectedItem` in the init, and when new item gets added it doesn't have enough items

You can add new `false` to this array somehow, but if you'd like to add new item in the begging, you'll have more problems with up-to-dating your `selectedItem` flags array

Instead of that I suggest you adding a unique identifier to your `Player` item and storing `Set` of this ids for selected player

```
struct PlayersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlayersViewModel

    @State var isSelected: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedIds = Set<String>()
    @State var selectedPlayers = [String]()

    init(viewModel: PlayersViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.players) { player in
                let selected = selectedIds.contains(player.id)
                Text("\(String(describing: selected)) \(player.playerName)")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if selected {
                            selectedIds.remove(player.id)
                        } else {
                            selectedIds.insert(player.id)
                        }
                        selectedPlayers = viewModel.players
                            .filter { selectedIds.contains($0.id) }
                            .map { $0.playerName }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Player: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let playerName: String
}

class PlayersViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var players = [Player]()
    
    init() {
        readJSON()
    }
    
    func saveJSON(username: String) {
        var array = players
        array.append(Player(id: UUID().uuidString, playerName: username))
        do {
            let fileURL = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent("example2.json")
            
            try JSONEncoder().encode(array)
                .write(to: fileURL)
            readJSON()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func readJSON() {
        do {
            let fileURL = try FileManager.default
                .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                .appendingPathComponent("example2.json")
            
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            let players = try JSONDecoder().decode([Player].self, from: data)
            self.players = players
            print(players)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```